# Why isn't my Heroku discord bot going online?

Tags: heroku, npm, discord.js

I'm programming a discord bot using discord.js and am trying to use Heroku to host the bot. 
When I deploy it Heroku says the deployment was successful but my bot is still offline in discord. When I check the log it shows :

```
2020-01-10T21:55:49.598875+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2020-01-10T21:55:49.599295+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! errno 1

2020-01-10T21:55:49.600878+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! funamibot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`

2020-01-10T21:55:49.601091+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1

2020-01-10T21:55:49.601329+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! 

2020-01-10T21:55:49.601552+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the funamibot@1.0.0 start script.

2020-01-10T21:55:49.601651+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2020-01-10T21:55:49.607761+00:00 app[worker.1]: 

2020-01-10T21:55:49.607944+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2020-01-10T21:55:49.608089+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-01-10T21_55_49_602Z-debug.log
```

From the error it gives it seems to do with the start script in the package.json file, but i'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

The bot code on github : https://github.com/Yunoxa/funamibot/

Comment: Is there move info above in the logs?

Comment: @PLASMAchicken Nope, that's everything that shows up in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You must include the versions to use for both **node** and **npm** (I'd recommend using the latest):

```
"engines": {
  "node": "12.14.1",
  "npm": "6.13.4"
},
```

However if you are using specific versions of either node or npm, do this and replace the version numbers I specified:

```
node -v (Returns the current version of Node you're running.)

npm -v (Returns the current version of NPM you're running.)
```

Comment: I added this but I am still getting the same error in the log.